# Power BI and Snowflake - replacing data source - errors troubleshoot with OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx020.png)

I have constantly occuring error when want to replace from one Snowflake role into another one the data source in power bi.
error sounds like this:OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. An unexpected exception occurred"
I was searching through knowledge base in internet, I found only that is a conflict between data types and autodetect types of columns in power bi.

I switched off auto detect on current file, in settings for current file in Power BI - not helped.
I update power BI version - not helped.
There is a difference between data types in both roles in snowflake - for database 1 I have columns varchar and timestamp, but in database 2 when switch the role in power bi, datatypes is all varchar. Hence I needed to replace data type - add a new step in M language when transforma data in Power Query. Because integrer, boolean types and timestamp where all changed during the extraction from another data source into snowflake, using script (I dont know exact what, It was made by another data engineer).name of databases in snowflake have only one difference - once name has DEV, everything is with *underscore*, no hyphen inside or strange character which could give connection error.
I changed all text type columns to appropriate one as it should be in the original data source, I have this error.
where I can find docuentation about troubke shooting? how can check the logs, to determine what causes that OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. An unexpected exception occurred? what means HRESULT: 0x80040E4E what is behind the scene?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message from the PBI logs and what was done that introduced the error?

Comment: Don't post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @SrinathMenon thank you for the reply. I am a new and ask for your patience when need to explain maybe some trivial issues. What exactly logs are you looking for? I dont see any error in M code, it runs correctly, error comes when apply and load changes in Power Query. I am not sure how can I extract these errors. I can only give the exact text of error: "Column reference to 'Resolved time'in table [Inc] cannot be used with a vaation "Date", because it does not have any. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRRESULT: 0x80040E4E. An unexpected exception occured. "

Comment: @SrinathMenon what was done that introduced the error:
database 1 has timestamp and varchar data types in snowflake. everything runs correct in power bi.
database 2 has changed data type only to varchar - so the previous timestamp columns are now varchar, And I add change type step in Power Query to bring back timestamp data type. Then it apperas the mentioned error. I assume is somehow related to timestamp-varchar data extraction but would lioke to understand what happened in the backstage.